# Is it possible to log all command/terminal output when a Windows installer runs.?

Tags: windows, logging, installer

Sometimes when running program installers, they run some scripts (DOS?) that momentarily splash on the screen. Is it possible to intercept and log all of this output on a logged-in system for review later?

Comment: What do you mean by this, “Sometimes when running program installers, they run some DOS scripts …” on modern Windows systems DOS is not a thing. So do you want to see a log of installer output?

Comment: Exactly that. You may notice some installers run various scripts, usually, clean-up scripts at the end of the installation but all you see is a dos window pop up momentarily. I'd like to capture what that installer just run through the cmd.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am mainly a macOS and Linux user but know enough about Windows that I know in 2022 one cannot assume those screens are DOS. Thus I reworked your question a but to better clarify things.

Comment: I use "DOS" incorrectly yes - just a habit, I mean the cmd. Thanks for the edit

Comment: “DOS prompts” do not exist in modern versions of Windows, which basically includes, any version built upon the NT kernel. Those prompts are likely a command prompt, which isn’t DOS, so it’s an important distinction.

Comment: Right, I stand corrected - just a habit. I call cmd DOS interchangeably

Comment: @David - Well it’s incorrect and confusing from a technical point of view, anyways, Windows doesn’t have a logging feature like your looking for.

Comment: I do believe there are 3rd party products that monitor the widows OS for changes related to an installation activity. they may not capture everything that runs, but the good ones may be able to capture all the actual changes to filesystem, registery, config files, etc. not endorsing any of these products, but here is an example https://www.raymond.cc/blog/monitor-software-installs-remove-leftovers-install-monitor/